# Пунктуация на стыке цельных по смыслу выражений

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, цельное-выражение

**Спит он где попало(?) когда придется.**
Если не использовать союз "и", нужна ли здесь запятая?
"Где попало" и "Когда придется" — это два цельных выражения.
Т. е. было бы: *Спит где попало; Спит когда придется.*
Можно ли считать "где попало когда придется" цельным выражением?

Другой пример:
Спать ему всё равно где и безразлично как: **спит он где попало(?) когда придется(?) и спит сколько захочет.**
Запятую нужно поставить только одну. Здесь "где попало" и "когда придется" как бы перечисляются. Если поставить запятую между ними, то не нужна ли будет запятая перед "и спит сколько захочет"? Меня здесь смущает повторение слова "спит".

Comment: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/50.htm - ссылка на правило

Answer (score 2):

Где попало, когда придется, сколько захочет - **цельные по смыслу выражения являются однородными обстоятельствами,** запятые ставятся по общим правилам для союзной или бессоюзной связи:

Спит он где попало, когда придется. Спит он где попало и когда придется. 
Спать ему всё равно где и безразлично как.

Спит он где попало, когда придется и спит сколько захочет (союз И соединяет однородные сказуемые).

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Мне кажется, что такие выражения в любом случае **приходится считать однородными** (обозначение одинаковых или сближенных признаков), так как они начинаются с союзного слова и должны разделяться или запятой, или союзом.

Comment: *так как они начинаются с союзного слова и должны разделяться или запятой, или союзом*  - и что? Я, кстати не уверенен, что  в данном случае корректно говорить о союзных словах. Союзные слова подобно союзам присоединяют придаточное, а у нас "где попало" и "когда придется" - члены основного предложения.

Comment: Если два таких оборота ничем не разделить (спит он где попало когда придется), то графика предложения будет сложна для прочтения, к тому же интонация здесь перечислительная, так как два оборота сложно связать в одну фразу. Примерно такая же ситуация наблюдается с  рядом определений, стоящим после определяемого слова: эти определения всегда считаются однородными из-за наличия перечислительной интонации (по дороге зимней, скучной…). Если же говорить о семантике, то цельные обороты обозначают сближенные признаки, так как раскрывают общую тему (спит неустроенно, кое-как).

Answer (score 0):

> Спит он где попало(,) когда придется.

Необходимость запятой полностью лежит на авторском понимании. Причем это тот нечастый случай, когда даже рекомендации автору давать трудно.

Мне ближе в**и**денье, что эти обстоятельства неоднородные, поскольку характеризуют процесс с совершенно разных точек зрения - времени и места. Поэтому запятой я бы не поставил.

С другой стороны, автор может видеть под этими двумя характеристиками единое целое - случайность или неполноценность процесса (а через него и героя). В таком случае запятая, понятно, нужна.

Ситуация в общем-то есть выбор между двумя равнодопустимыми возможностями авторского понимания. В такой ситуации пунктуация лучше помогает понять автора, если, конечно, автор вполне владеет этим аппаратом.

> Т.е. было бы: Cпит где попало; Спит когда придется.

Это не поддается моему пониманию. Зачем точка с запятой, зачем заглавная после неё? И самое главное, почему вы считаете, что при каких-то обстоятельствах это "т. е. было бы"?!

> Спать ему всё равно где и безразлично как: спит он где попало() когда придется() и спит сколько захочет

Несколько странная по смыслу и по построению конструкция. Но в принципе та же ситуация. 
Вторая запятая заведомо не нужна, поскольку тут очевидно однородные сказуемые. Ни группа второго сказуемого, ни первая же часть составного предложения, которая у вас идет до двоеточия (зачем оно там?), никак не влияют на выбор пунктуации при обстоятельствах первого "спит".

Comment: Т.е. было бы: Cпит где попало; Спит когда придется. - Это я так показал варианты разных предложений с этими двумя выражениями, с намерением уточнить  цельность последних. Точкой с запятой я просто разграничил примеры, потому что не знаю как правильно всё это оформлять.

Comment: Ни группа второго сказуемого, ни первая же часть составного предложения, которая у вас идет до двоеточия (зачем оно там?), никак не влияют на выбор пунктуации при обстоятельствах первого "спит". - Вот это не понял. Зачем здесь "на выбор пунктуации при обстоятельствах **первого** 'спит'", если вы перед этим говорите,что именно "**вторая** запятая заведомо не нужна"?

Comment: @IliaRazbitnoi , 1. У вас две сомнительные запятые. 2. Вторая заведомо не нужна. У вас два однородных сказуемых ("спит" и "спит"), соединенных союзом "и". Поэтому запятая не нужна (некоторые сложности в том, что это повторяющиеся сказуемые, но не думаю, что тут можно запутаться). 3. a) У второго сказуемого есть относящиеся к ней члены "сколько захочет". б) В первой части сложного предложения (той, что у вас до двоеточия) тоже есть какие осложняющие члены.  Так вот я утверждаю, что ни a), ни б) ***никак на выбор пунктуации в случае с первой вашей сомнительной запятой не влияют***.

Comment: *Точкой с запятой я просто разграничил примеры, потому что не знаю как правильно всё это оформлять.* - ничего не понял. Оформляйте как угодно, только приведите все свои предложения так, что было понятно, где начинается и кончается каждый пример. С заглавными и точками. Кавычки, в конце концов, никто не отменял. Можете по одному на строку.